# Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. The Certified Intermediary’s pass phrase is incorrect. Error encountered in Quote save

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Netsuite trying to change the shipping method in an Estimate record creation.
Unable to save the record. It returns the following error.

*Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. The Certified Intermediary’s pass phrase is incorrect. Error encountered*

Comment: Are you using a third party for shipping functions? Pacejet, perhaps?

Comment: No, we use NetSuite standard feature. Trying to save the record with the shipping method. We face a similar error. _Could not calculate cost for the selected Realtime rate. The rate for this service is not available for the specified source and destination addresses_